# Can I fetch Google Maps Events through the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I've just seen that Google Maps has an option "Events" in a few cities (London, Zurich,... etc). I need them for a project.

Is there a way to get these results with Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no events function in the Maps API. It's likely the site you saw was using another data source with the Maps API. What's the fun of a mashup if everything is in the same API? :)